# audioplayer kotlin version in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':audioplayers' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21

````
```audioplayers: ^0.18.0
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0"
} ```
````